# Processing http post array, display undefined

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, post

I have the big problem. I want to display this json, but returning undefined value.

```
{"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription":{ "datas": [
{"sensor_serial":"SensorSerial1", "id":"11E807676E3F30B5"},
{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial2", "id":"11E807679D82841L"},
{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial3", "id":"11E80767A5CD2820"} ]
,"home_id":"11E80768K", "active":0, "homebox_id":"11E8076792BD0164J",
"date_created":"2018-02-01T15:55:54.000Z", "date_modified":null,
"serial_number":"serialn1", "user_id":"3"} }
```

I use this code in service.ts

```
public getHomeboxPById(id: string): Observable<HomeboxP> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('home_id', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getHomeboxPById), body, {
    headers: headers
    })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
         return new HomeboxP(res.StatusDescription[0]);
        } else if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
         this.auth.logout();
        } else {
           return new HomeboxP(null);
        }
    });
}
```

In ts code I call this method getHomeboxPById, like this

```
editHomeboxPForm: FormGroup;
homeboxp: HomeboxP;
    this.editHomeboxPForm = this.fb.group({
      'homebox_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
}

populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    params => {
    this.ws.getHomeboxPById(params['id']).subscribe(
     homeboxp => {
        console.log(homeboxp);  // display undefined
        this.homeboxp = homeboxp;
        this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['homebox_id'].setValue(homeboxp.homebox_id);
        }
      );
     }
   );   
}
```

Please, can you help me, why doesn't work?

Comment: Ist there an error code? Please describe how "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription":{ "datas": [
{"sensor_serial":"SensorSerial1", "id":"11E807676E3F30B5"},
{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial2", "id":"11E807679D82841L"},
{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial3", "id":"11E80767A5CD2820"} ]
,"home_id":"11E80768K", "active":0, "homebox_id":"11E8076792BD0164J",
"date_created":"2018-02-01T15:55:54.000Z", "date_modified":null,
"serial_number":"serialn1", "user_id":"3"} }
```

If this is the response of

```
this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getHomeboxPById)
```

Then issue is `res.StatusDescription[0]` , it should be `res.StatusDescription` like :

```
new HomeboxP(res.StatusDescription);
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek, this is problem.